# Path-connectedness of the fiber ine the LSAH spectral sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

I've read some proofs of the identification of the second term of the Leray-Serre-Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence, and I don't quite seem to understand where in the proof do we need the fiber of the fibration of interest to be path-connected? Moreover, are there `counter-examples´, when the fiber is not path-connected?

Comment: I've always assumed it necessary that $F$ be connected, although most authors do not seem to make this requirement. McCleary does, Selick, May, Davis-Kirk, Hatcher, Strom and Spanier do not.

What about the homotopy fibration $\mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow S^1\xrightarrow{2}S^1$? The coefficient system should be trivial and it should should collapse, but the standard formula for the $E_2$-page does not give the correct abutment.

Comment: You might like to read Barnes's "Spectral Sequence Constructors in Algebra and Topology", section XIV.5, pg 165. For a more general construction than most where the connectivity condition *is* required.

Comment: I see, but I still don't understand which step of the proof uses this assumption, and this bothers me...

Comment: I do understand. McCleary's book is known for being fairly encyclopedic, but also containing a few errors. One thing he also does fairly frequently is provide statements that are more general than they need to be. This isn't a criticism of his work: what he set out to accomplish in writing the book is a truly gargantuan task. I'd suggest letting the minor errors slip by and consulting more rigorous proofs in other texts for the results that bother you.